# How to revert MySQL database update (PHPMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I accidentally inserted the same value in the same field for many rows as illustrated in the image below:

[image: mysql problem]

I updated my table and the same file name was uploaded into every row in the table.

What SQL command can I use to revert this unintended modification?

Comment: The `delete` sql command.

Comment: That looks like PHPMyAdmin so I'm guessing you're using MySQL. In that you could do as the other comment suggests and delete them like this:.  DELETE FROM companies WHERE name = [repeatedCompanyName] AND id != IdOfCompanyToNotDelete

Comment: Do you actually want to **delete** the affected fields or **revert** the unintended multiple insertion you made?

Comment: @RoboBear I did this and it deleted every row except for one. At least I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what I like to do when doing a `delete` statement that isn't by primary key is to select the result first..

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='Sprouts';`

If that result set is correct, then you can feel fairly safe swapping in the `delete`

`DELETE FROM table WHERE name='Sprouts';`